# android code for streaming shoutcast stream breaks in 2.2

Tags: android, audio-streaming, shoutcast

The following code works fine on Android 2.1update1 -

```
package com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class TestStreaming extends Activity 
{
 private Button streamButton;

 private ImageButton playButton;

 private TextView textStreamed;

 private boolean isPlaying;

 private StreamingMediaPlayer audioStreamer;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  initControls();


 }
 protected void onDestroy()
 {
  super.onDestroy();

  Toast.makeText(TestStreaming.this, "...exiting application..." ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  if ( audioStreamer != null) 
  {
   audioStreamer.interrupt();
  }

 }

 private void initControls()
 {
  textStreamed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_kb_streamed);
  streamButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stream);
  streamButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
   public void onClick(View view)
   {

    String urlstring2 = "url to a shoutcase stream";


    Toast
    .makeText(
      TestStreaming.this,
       "The following stream is about to start" + urlstring2,   
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    startStreamingAudio(urlstring2);
   }
  });

  playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_play);
  playButton.setEnabled(false);
  playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
   public void onClick(View view)
   {
    if (audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().isPlaying())
    {
     audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().pause();
     playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
    } else
    {
     audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().start();
     audioStreamer.startPlayProgressUpdater();
     playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
    }
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
   }
  });
 }
 private void startStreamingAudio(String urlstring) {
  try { 
   final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
   if ( audioStreamer != null) {
    audioStreamer.interrupt();
   }
   audioStreamer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(this,textStreamed, playButton, streamButton,progressBar);
   audioStreamer.startStreaming(urlstring,5208, 216);
   streamButton.setEnabled(false);
  } catch (Exception e) 
  {
   Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error starting to stream audio.", e);                  
  }

 }

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
 {
  mSwitcher.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
 }

 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent)
 {
 }

 public View makeView()
 {
  ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
  i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
  i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
  i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
  return i;
 }

 private ImageSwitcher mSwitcher;

 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
  public ImageAdapter(Context c)
  {
   mContext = c;
  }

  public int getCount()
  {
   return mThumbIds.length;
  }

  public Object getItem(int position)
  {
   return position;
  }

  public long getItemId(int position)
  {
   return position;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
   ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

   i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
   i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
   i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture_frame);
   return i;
  }

  private Context mContext;

 }

 private Integer[] mThumbIds =
 { R.drawable.calculator, R.drawable.calendar, R.drawable.camera };

 private Integer[] mImageIds =
 { R.drawable.calculator, R.drawable.calendar, R.drawable.camera };

}
```

with the StreamingMediaPlayer class as follows -

```
package com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * MediaPlayer does not yet support streaming from external URLs so this class
 * provides a pseudo-streaming function by downloading the content incrementally
 * & playing as soon as we get enough audio in our temporary storage.
 */
public class StreamingMediaPlayer
{

 private static final int INTIAL_KB_BUFFER = 96 * 10 / 8;// assume
               // 96kbps*10secs/8bits
               // per byte



 private TextView textStreamed;

 private ImageButton playButton;

 private ProgressBar progressBar;

 // Track for display by progressBar
 private long mediaLengthInKb, mediaLengthInSeconds;

 private int totalKbRead = 0;

 // Create Handler to call View updates on the main UI thread.
 private final Handler handler = new Handler();

 private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

 private File downloadingMediaFile;

 private boolean isInterrupted;

 private Context context;

 private int counter = 0;

 public StreamingMediaPlayer(Context context, TextView textStreamed,
   ImageButton playButton, Button streamButton, ProgressBar progressBar)
 {
  this.context = context;
  this.textStreamed = textStreamed;
  this.playButton = playButton;
  this.progressBar = progressBar;
 }

 /**
  * Progressivly download the media to a temporary location and update the
  * MediaPlayer as new content becomes available.
  */
 public void startStreaming(final String mediaUrl, long mediaLengthInKb,
   long mediaLengthInSeconds) throws IOException
 {

  this.mediaLengthInKb = mediaLengthInKb;
  this.mediaLengthInSeconds = mediaLengthInSeconds;

  Runnable r = new Runnable()
  {
   public void run()
   {
    try
    {
     downloadAudioIncrement(mediaUrl);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
     Log.e(getClass().getName(),
       "Unable to initialize the MediaPlayer for fileUrl="
         + mediaUrl, e);
     return;
    }
   }
  };
  new Thread(r).start();
 }

 /**
  * Download the url stream to a temporary location and then call the
  * setDataSource for that local file
  */
 public void downloadAudioIncrement(String mediaUrl) throws IOException
 {

  URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();
  cn.connect();
  InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
  if (stream == null)
  {
   Log.e(getClass().getName(),
     "Unable to create InputStream for mediaUrl:" + mediaUrl);
  }

  downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),
    "downloadingMedia.dat");

  // Just in case a prior deletion failed because our code crashed or
  // something, we also delete any previously
  // downloaded file to ensure we start fresh. If you use this code,
  // always delete
  // no longer used downloads else you'll quickly fill up your hard disk
  // memory. Of course, you can also
  // store any previously downloaded file in a separate data cache for
  // instant replay if you wanted as well.
  if (downloadingMediaFile.exists())
  {
   downloadingMediaFile.delete();
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);
  byte buf[] = new byte[16384];
  int totalBytesRead = 0, incrementalBytesRead = 0;
  do
  {
   int numread = stream.read(buf);
   if (numread <= 0)
    break;
   out.write(buf, 0, numread);
   totalBytesRead += numread;
   incrementalBytesRead += numread;
   totalKbRead = totalBytesRead / 1000;

   testMediaBuffer();
   fireDataLoadUpdate();
  } while (validateNotInterrupted());
  stream.close();
  if (validateNotInterrupted())
  {
   fireDataFullyLoaded();
  }
 }

 private boolean validateNotInterrupted()
 {
  if (isInterrupted)
  {
   if (mediaPlayer != null)
   {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    // mediaPlayer.release();
   }
   return false;
  } else
  {
   return true;
  }
 }

 /**
  * Test whether we need to transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
  * Interacting with MediaPlayer on non-main UI thread can causes crashes to
  * so perform this using a Handler.
  */
 private void testMediaBuffer()
 {
  Runnable updater = new Runnable()
  {
   public void run()
   {
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
    {
     // Only create the MediaPlayer once we have the minimum
     // buffered data
     if (totalKbRead >= INTIAL_KB_BUFFER)
     {
      try
      {
       startMediaPlayer();
      } catch (Exception e)
      {
       Log.e(getClass().getName(),
         "Error copying buffered conent.", e);
      }
     }
    } else if (mediaPlayer.getDuration()
      - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000)
    {
     // NOTE: The media player has stopped at the end so transfer
     // any existing buffered data
     // We test for < 1second of data because the media player
     // can stop when there is still
     // a few milliseconds of data left to play
     transferBufferToMediaPlayer();
    }
   }
  };
  handler.post(updater);
 }

 private void startMediaPlayer()
 {
  try
  {
   File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "playingMedia"
     + (counter++) + ".dat");

   // We double buffer the data to avoid potential read/write errors
   // that could happen if the
   // download thread attempted to write at the same time the
   // MediaPlayer was trying to read.
   // For example, we can't guarantee that the MediaPlayer won't open a
   // file for playing and leave it locked while
   // the media is playing. This would permanently deadlock the file
   // download. To avoid such a deadloack,
   // we move the currently loaded data to a temporary buffer file that
   // we start playing while the remaining
   // data downloads.
   moveFile(downloadingMediaFile, bufferedFile);

   Log.e(getClass().getName(),
     "Buffered File path: " + bufferedFile.getAbsolutePath());
   Log.e(getClass().getName(),
     "Buffered File length: " + bufferedFile.length() + "");

   mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(bufferedFile);

   // We have pre-loaded enough content and started the MediaPlayer so
   // update the buttons & progress meters.
   mediaPlayer.start();
   startPlayProgressUpdater();
   playButton.setEnabled(true);
  } catch (IOException e)
  {
   Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error initializing the MediaPlayer.",
     e);
   return;
  }
 }

 private MediaPlayer createMediaPlayer(File mediaFile) throws IOException
 {
  MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener()
  {
   public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
   {
    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error in MediaPlayer: (" + what
      + ") with extra (" + extra + ")");
    return false;
   }
  });

  // It appears that for security/permission reasons, it is better to pass
  // a FileDescriptor rather than a direct path to the File.
  // Also I have seen errors such as "PVMFErrNotSupported" and
  // "Prepare failed.: status=0x1" if a file path String is passed to
  // setDataSource(). So unless otherwise noted, we use a FileDescriptor
  // here.
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mediaFile);
  mPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
  mPlayer.prepare();
  return mPlayer;
 }

 /**
  * Transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer. NOTE: Interacting with a
  * MediaPlayer on a non-main UI thread can cause thread-lock and crashes so
  * this method should always be called using a Handler.
  */
 private void transferBufferToMediaPlayer()
 {
  try
  {
   // First determine if we need to restart the player after
   // transferring data...e.g. perhaps the user pressed pause
   boolean wasPlaying = mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
   int curPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

   // Copy the currently downloaded content to a new buffered File.
   // Store the old File for deleting later.
   File oldBufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),
     "playingMedia" + counter + ".dat");
   File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "playingMedia"
     + (counter++) + ".dat");

   // This may be the last buffered File so ask that it be delete on
   // exit. If it's already deleted, then this won't mean anything. If
   // you want to
   // keep and track fully downloaded files for later use, write
   // caching code and please send me a copy.
   bufferedFile.deleteOnExit();
   moveFile(downloadingMediaFile, bufferedFile);

   // Pause the current player now as we are about to create and start
   // a new one. So far (Android v1.5),
   // this always happens so quickly that the user never realized we've
   // stopped the player and started a new one
   mediaPlayer.pause();

   // Create a new MediaPlayer rather than try to re-prepare the prior
   // one.
   mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(bufferedFile);
   mediaPlayer.seekTo(curPosition);

   // Restart if at end of prior buffered content or mediaPlayer was
   // previously playing.
   // NOTE: We test for < 1second of data because the media player can
   // stop when there is still
   // a few milliseconds of data left to play
   boolean atEndOfFile = mediaPlayer.getDuration()
     - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000;
   if (wasPlaying || atEndOfFile)
   {
    mediaPlayer.start();
   }

   // Lastly delete the previously playing buffered File as it's no
   // longer needed.
   oldBufferedFile.delete();

  } catch (Exception e)
  {
   Log.e(getClass().getName(),
     "Error updating to newly loaded content.", e);
  }
 }

 private void fireDataLoadUpdate()
 {
  Runnable updater = new Runnable()
  {
   public void run()
   {
    textStreamed.setText((totalKbRead + " Kb read"));
    float loadProgress = ((float) totalKbRead / (float) mediaLengthInKb);
    progressBar.setSecondaryProgress((int) (loadProgress * 100));
   }
  };
  handler.post(updater);
 }

 private void fireDataFullyLoaded()
 {
  Runnable updater = new Runnable()
  {
   public void run()
   {
    transferBufferToMediaPlayer();

    // Delete the downloaded File as it's now been transferred to
    // the currently playing buffer file.
    downloadingMediaFile.delete();
    textStreamed
      .setText(("Audio full loaded: " + totalKbRead + " Kb read"));
   }
  };
  handler.post(updater);
 }

 public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer()
 {
  return mediaPlayer;
 }

 public void startPlayProgressUpdater()
 {
  float progress = (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000) / mediaLengthInSeconds);
  progressBar.setProgress((int) (progress * 100));

  if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
  {
   Runnable notification = new Runnable()
   {
    public void run()
    {
     startPlayProgressUpdater();
    }
   };
   handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
  }
 }

 public void interrupt()
 {
  playButton.setEnabled(false);
  isInterrupted = true;
  validateNotInterrupted();
 }

 /**
  * Move the file in oldLocation to newLocation.
  */
 public void moveFile(File oldLocation, File newLocation) throws IOException
 {

  if (oldLocation.exists())
  {
   BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(
     new FileInputStream(oldLocation));
   BufferedOutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(
     new FileOutputStream(newLocation, false));
   try
   {
    // byte[] buff = new byte[8192];
    /* changing the size of the buffer */

    byte[] buff = new byte[16384];

    int numChars;
    while ((numChars = reader.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1)
    {
     writer.write(buff, 0, numChars);
    }
   } catch (IOException ex)
   {
    throw new IOException("IOException when transferring "
      + oldLocation.getPath() + " to "
      + newLocation.getPath());
   } finally
   {
    try
    {
     if (reader != null)
     {
      writer.close();
      reader.close();
     }
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
     Log.e(getClass().getName(),
       "Error closing files when transferring "
         + oldLocation.getPath() + " to "
         + newLocation.getPath());
    }
   }
  } else
  {
   throw new IOException(
     "Old location does not exist when transferring "
       + oldLocation.getPath() + " to "
       + newLocation.getPath());
  }
 }
}
```

and the layout file as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/Logo"
 android:orientation="vertical">


 <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10px">

 <TextView   android:id="@+id/text_kb_streamed"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="...streaming audio..."/>

  <Button android:id="@+id/button_stream"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="10px"
   style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
   android:text="Start Streaming"/>


 <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress_bar"  
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/button_play"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="5px"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
     android:src="@drawable/button_pause"/>

</LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
  <ViewFlipper
 android:id="@+id/MainFlipper"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_below="@+id/Logo"
 android:layout_marginBottom="37dip">
  </ViewFlipper>
  <FrameLayout
 android:id="@+id/MediaPlayer"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="130dip"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
  </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the same code does not work in Android 2.2. Can it be fixed up to run on 2.2 ?

Here's the error I am getting -

```
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423): Error initializing the MediaPlayer.
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:749)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer.createMediaPlayer(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:272)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer.startMediaPlayer(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:237)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer.access$2(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:212)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer$2.run(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:190)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/global  ( 1423): Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
I/global  ( 1423): Default buffer size used in BufferedOutputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423): Buffered File path: /data/data/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming/cache/playingMedia34.dat
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423): Buffered File length: 193188
E/MediaPlayer( 1423): Unable to to create media player
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423): Error initializing the MediaPlayer.
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:749)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer.createMediaPlayer(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:272)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer.startMediaPlayer(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:237)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer.access$2(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:212)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer$2.run(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:190)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423):       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/global  ( 1423): Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
I/global  ( 1423): Default buffer size used in BufferedOutputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423): Buffered File path: /data/data/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming/cache/playingMedia35.dat
E/com.troubadorian.android.teststreaming.StreamingMediaPlayer( 1423): Buffered File length: 194588
E/MediaPlayer( 1423): Unable to to create media player
```

Please help.

Comment: I am facing this same issue. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Sorry to ask you again!!
Can you share the solution? i am facing the same issue.

Comment: How to play SHOUTcast?http://stackoverflow.com/a/8833346/265167

Comment: Could any one help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264225/andriod-shoutcast-internet-radio-filenotfoundexception

Comment: Can any one Share the answer to this Question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I traced your error a little bit...
Looking down in Froyo's source code, in frameworks/base/media/libmedia/mediaplayer.cpp, it comes down to this function.
At this point, apparently the `player` argument is NULL

```
status_t MediaPlayer::setDataSource(const sp<IMediaPlayer>& player)
{
    status_t err = UNKNOWN_ERROR;
    sp<IMediaPlayer> p;
    { // scope for the lock
        Mutex::Autolock _l(mLock);

        if ( !( (mCurrentState & MEDIA_PLAYER_IDLE) ||
                (mCurrentState == MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR ) ) ) {
            LOGE("setDataSource called in state %d", mCurrentState);
            return INVALID_OPERATION;
        }

        clear_l();
        p = mPlayer;
        mPlayer = player;
        if (player != 0) {
            mCurrentState = MEDIA_PLAYER_INITIALIZED;
            err = NO_ERROR;
        } else {
            LOGE("Unable to to create media player");
        }
    }

    if (p != 0) {
        p->disconnect();
    }

    return err;
}
```

That came from the function `status_t MediaPlayer::setDataSource(const char *url, const KeyedVector<String8, String8> *headers)` from the same file, where it was able to instantiate the `IMediaPlayerService`, but the `create` method must have failed for some reason...

One thing from the [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MediaPlayer%28%29) :
When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the resources. If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances may result in an exception.

Maybe you should check the `createMediaPlayer` function is called only once ? I guess that would have failed also with Eclair, but may be worth looking into...

Or maybe what you are looking at is what is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9787)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for looking into where the problem lies in the Android implementation.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... I was going to tweak that code and do something else with it - but it won't work at all on 2.2.  Did you figure it out??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264225/andriod-shoutcast-internet-radio-filenotfoundexception  Could you help me?  @Matthieu

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error with my MediaPlayer code. I had various results playing simple test.ogg file located in the raw directory. My AVD's were able to play the file, SE Xperia Mini Pro played the sound, but my Samsung SII crashed using the simple code below.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.getBaseContext(), R.raw.test);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

I received the same error like you

```
Error initializing the MediaPlayer.
java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.
```

I further tested playing the file over the local network with expected results for both phones (SE played the file and Samsung could not play it). This pretty much means that different Android versions are unable to play the same sound and you need to use difference audio format.

If the phone is unable to play the file natively, the only workaround for me is to resample the audio.

Comment: hepl please  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264225/andriod-shoutcast-internet-radio-filenotfoundexception   ?

Comment: you didn't prepare the media player