# Android ShoutCast Internet Radio FilenotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-intent, streaming

I developed Shoutcastinternet Radio Streaming(Stream URL:`http://123.176.41.8:8256`) in Andriod and i'm able to stream and play Successfully.

But the problem is: when i execute my application,I'm able to stream and play Continuously for someextend(20min,halfanhour etc...),

after that the stream is getting stoped(I'm not ableto play the stream),Could any one help?

I logged the Error,after Stream get Stopped.

```
The Error is:
D/dalvikvm(1238): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 51742 objects / 1928072 bytes in 80ms(I'm repeating this statement in the log file while running my application on real Device)
```

**Update:**
 **Exception:**

```
  04-27 18:31:05.753: V/MediaPlayer(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.753: E/MediaPlayer(26201): start called in state 1
04-27 18:31:05.753: E/MediaPlayer(26201): message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
04-27 18:31:05.753: E/MediaPlayer(26201): error (-38, 0)
04-27 18:31:05.753: E/MediaPlayer(26201): callback application
04-27 18:31:05.753: E/MediaPlayer(26201): back from callback
04-27 18:31:05.753: E/setupplayer(26201): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.torilt/cache/downloadingMediaFile591 (No such file or directory)
04-27 18:31:05.753: E/setupplayer(26201): Can't find file. Android must have deleted it on a clean up 
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/MediaPlayer(26201): Error (-38,0)
04-27 18:31:05.757: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.757: V/MediaPlayer(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.757: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.757: V/MediaPlayer(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/MediaPlayer(26201): start called in state 1
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/MediaPlayer(26201): message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/MediaPlayer(26201): error (-38, 0)
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/MediaPlayer(26201): callback application
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/MediaPlayer(26201): back from callback
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/setupplayer(26201): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.torilt/cache/downloadingMediaFile591 (No such file or directory)
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/setupplayer(26201): Can't find file. Android must have deleted it on a clean up 
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/MediaPlayer(26201): Error (-38,0)
04-27 18:31:05.757: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.757: V/MediaPlayer(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.757: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.757: V/MediaPlayer(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/MediaPlayer(26201): start called in state 1
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/MediaPlayer(26201): message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/MediaPlayer(26201): error (-38, 0)
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/MediaPlayer(26201): callback application
04-27 18:31:05.757: E/MediaPlayer(26201): back from callback
04-27 18:31:05.761: E/setupplayer(26201): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.torilt/cache/downloadingMediaFile591 (No such file or directory)
04-27 18:31:05.761: E/setupplayer(26201): Can't find file. Android must have deleted it on a clean up 
04-27 18:31:05.761: E/setupplayer(26201): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.torilt/cache/downloadingMediaFile591 (No such file or directory)
04-27 18:31:05.761: E/setupplayer(26201): Can't find file. Android must have deleted it on a clean up 
04-27 18:31:05.761: E/MediaPlayer(26201): Error (-38,0)
04-27 18:31:05.761: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.761: V/MediaPlayer(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.761: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.761: V/MediaPlayer(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.761: E/MediaPlayer(26201): start called in state 1
04-27 18:31:05.761: E/MediaPlayer(26201): message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
04-27 18:31:05.761: E/MediaPlayer(26201): error (-38, 0)
04-27 18:31:05.761: E/MediaPlayer(26201): callback application
04-27 18:31:05.761: E/MediaPlayer(26201): back from callback
04-27 18:31:05.765: E/setupplayer(26201): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.torilt/cache/downloadingMediaFile591 (No such file or directory)
04-27 18:31:05.765: E/setupplayer(26201): Can't find file. Android must have deleted it on a clean up 
04-27 18:31:05.765: E/MediaPlayer(26201): Error (-38,0)
04-27 18:31:05.765: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.765: V/MediaPlayer(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.765: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.765: V/MediaPlayer(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.765: E/MediaPlayer(26201): start called in state 1
04-27 18:31:05.765: E/MediaPlayer(26201): message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
04-27 18:31:05.765: E/MediaPlayer(26201): error (-38, 0)
04-27 18:31:05.765: E/MediaPlayer(26201): callback application
04-27 18:31:05.765: E/MediaPlayer(26201): back from callback
04-27 18:31:05.765: E/setupplayer(26201): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.torilt/cache/downloadingMediaFile591 (No such file or directory)
04-27 18:31:05.765: E/setupplayer(26201): Can't find file. Android must have deleted it on a clean up 
04-27 18:31:05.769: E/MediaPlayer(26201): Error (-38,0)
04-27 18:31:05.769: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.769: V/MediaPlayer(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.769: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.769: V/MediaPlayer(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.769: E/MediaPlayer(26201): start called in state 1
04-27 18:31:05.769: E/MediaPlayer(26201): message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
04-27 18:31:05.769: E/MediaPlayer(26201): error (-38, 0)
04-27 18:31:05.769: E/MediaPlayer(26201): callback application
04-27 18:31:05.769: E/MediaPlayer(26201): back from callback
04-27 18:31:05.769: E/setupplayer(26201): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.torilt/cache/downloadingMediaFile591 (No such file or directory)
04-27 18:31:05.769: E/setupplayer(26201): Can't find file. Android must have deleted it on a clean up 
04-27 18:31:05.769: E/MediaPlayer(26201): Error (-38,0)
04-27 18:31:05.769: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.769: V/MediaPlayer(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.773: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.773: V/MediaPlayer(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.773: E/MediaPlayer(26201): start called in state 1
04-27 18:31:05.773: E/MediaPlayer(26201): message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
04-27 18:31:05.773: E/MediaPlayer(26201): error (-38, 0)
04-27 18:31:05.773: E/MediaPlayer(26201): callback application
04-27 18:31:05.773: E/MediaPlayer(26201): back from callback
04-27 18:31:05.773: E/setupplayer(26201): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.torilt/cache/downloadingMediaFile591 (No such file or directory)
04-27 18:31:05.773: E/setupplayer(26201): Can't find file. Android must have deleted it on a clean up 
04-27 18:31:05.773: E/setupplayer(26201): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.torilt/cache/downloadingMediaFile591 (No such file or directory)
04-27 18:31:05.773: E/setupplayer(26201): Can't find file. Android must have deleted it on a clean up 
04-27 18:31:05.773: E/MediaPlayer(26201): Error (-38,0)
04-27 18:31:05.773: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.773: V/MediaPlayer(26201): reset
04-27 18:31:05.776: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.776: V/MediaPlayer(26201): start
04-27 18:31:05.776: E/MediaPlayer(26201): start called in state 1
04-27 18:31:05.776: E/MediaPlayer(26201): message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
```

Source Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Process;
import android.util.Log;
/** 
 * MediaPlayer does not yet support "Shoutcast"-like streaming from external
 * URLs so this class provides a pseudo-streaming function by downloading the
 * content incrementally & playing as soon as we get enough audio in our
 * temporary storage.
 */
public class StreamingMediaPlayer extends Service {

    final static public String AUDIO_MPEG = "audio/mpeg";
    final static public String BITERATE_HEADER = "icy-br";
    public int INTIAL_KB_BUFFER ;
    private Handler handler;
    //= 96*10/8
    final public int BIT = 8;
    final public int SECONDS = 60;
    int bitrate = 56;

    public File downloadingMediaFile;
    final public String DOWNFILE = "downloadingMediaFile";

    public Context context;
    public int counter;
    public int playedcounter;
    public int preparecounter;

    public MediaPlayer mp1;
    public MediaPlayer mp2;
    public boolean mp1prepared;
    public boolean mp2prepared;
    public boolean mp1preparing;
    public boolean mp2preparing;
    public boolean downloadingformp1;
    public boolean downloadingformp2;
    public boolean prepareState;
    public String SONGURL = "";

    // playing is "true" for mp1 and "false" for mp2
    public boolean mp1playing;

    public boolean started;
    public boolean processHasStarted;
    public boolean processHasPaused;
    public boolean regularStream;

    public BufferedInputStream stream;

    public URL url;
    public URLConnection urlConn;

    public String station;
    public String audiourl;

    public Intent startingIntent = null;

    public boolean stopping;
    Thread preparringthread;

    boolean waitingForPlayer;

    // Setup all the variables
    private void setupVars() {
        counter = 0;
        playedcounter = 0;
        preparecounter = 0;

        mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
        mp2 = new MediaPlayer();

        mp1prepared = false;
        mp2prepared = false;
        mp1preparing = false;
        mp2preparing = false;
        downloadingformp1 = false;
        downloadingformp2 = false;
        prepareState = true;
        mp1playing = false;

        started = false;
        processHasStarted = false;
        processHasPaused = true;
        regularStream = false;
        stream = null;

        url = null;
        urlConn = null;

        station = null;
        audiourl = null;

        stopping = false;
        preparringthread = null;

        waitingForPlayer = false;
    }

    // This object will allow other processes to interact with our service
    private final IStreamingMediaPlayer.Stub ourBinder = new IStreamingMediaPlayer.Stub() {
        // String TAG = "IStreamingMediaPlayer.Stub";

        public String getStation() {
            // Log.d(TAG, "getStation");
            return station;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            // Log.d(TAG, "getUrl");
            return audiourl;
        }

        public boolean playing() {
            // Log.d(TAG, "playing?");
            return isPlaying();
        }

        public boolean pause() {
            // Log.d(TAG, "playing?");
            return isPause();
        }

        public void startAudio() {
            // Log.d(TAG, "startAudio");

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    onStart(startingIntent, 0);
                }
            };
            new Thread(r).start();

        }

        public void stopAudio() {
            // Log.d(TAG, "stopAudio");
            stop();
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) throws NullPointerException {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        // final String TAG = "StreamingMediaPlayer - onStart";

        context = this;




        setupVars();

        if (intent.hasExtra("audiourl")) {
            raiseThreadPriority();
            processHasStarted = true;
            processHasPaused = false;

            audiourl = intent.getStringExtra("audiourl");
            station = intent.getStringExtra("station");


            downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), DOWNFILE+ counter);
            downloadingMediaFile.deleteOnExit();

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {


                        startStreaming(audiourl);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp1.stop();
        mp2.stop();
    }



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        startingIntent = intent;
        context = this;
        return ourBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        super.onUnbind(intent);

        stopSelf();

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Progressivly download the media to a temporary location and update the
     * MediaPlayer as new content becomes available.
     */
    public void startStreaming(final String mediaUrl) throws IOException {

        try {
            url = new URL(mediaUrl);
            urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConn.setReadTimeout(1000 * 20);
            urlConn.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 5);
            //The getContentType method is used by the getContent method to determine the type of the remote object; subclasses may find it convenient to override the getContentType method. 
            String ctype = urlConn.getContentType();
            if (ctype == null) {
                ctype = "";
            } else {
                ctype = ctype.toLowerCase();
            }

            if (ctype.contains(AUDIO_MPEG) || ctype.equals("")) {

                String temp = urlConn.getHeaderField(BITERATE_HEADER);

                if (temp != null) {
                    bitrate = new Integer(temp).intValue();
                }
            } else {

                stopSelf();
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException ne)
        {

        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            // Log.e(TAG, "Could not connect to " + mediaUrl);
            stopSelf();
            return;
        }


        if (!regularStream) {

            INTIAL_KB_BUFFER = bitrate * SECONDS / BIT;

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        downloadAudioIncrement(mediaUrl);
                        Log.i("TAG12344444", "Unable to play");
                        stopSelf();
                        return;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.i("TAG123", "Unable to initialize the MediaPlayer for Audio Url = "+mediaUrl, e);
                        stopSelf();
                        return;
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                        stopSelf();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread t = new Thread(r);

            t.start();
        }
    }



    /**
     * Download the url stream to a temporary location and then call the
     * setDataSource for that local file
     */
    public void downloadAudioIncrement(String mediaUrl) throws IOException{

        int bufsizeForDownload = 8 * 1024;
        int bufsizeForfile = 64 * 1024;

        stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream(),bufsizeForDownload);
        Log.i("bufsize",Integer.toString(urlConn.getInputStream().available()));

        try{
            if(stream == null || stream.available() == 0){
                stopSelf();
                Log.i("unable to create ","stream null");
                return;
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e) {
            stopSelf();
            Log.i("return1","return1");
            return;
        }


        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile), bufsizeForfile);

        byte buf[] = new byte[bufsizeForDownload];
        int totalBytesRead = 0, totalKbRead = 0, numread = 0;

        do {
            if (bout == null) {
                counter++;

                downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), DOWNFILE+ counter);
                downloadingMediaFile.deleteOnExit();
                bout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile), bufsizeForfile);
            }

            try {

                numread = stream.read(buf);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.d("Downloadingfile", "Bad read. Let's quit.");
                // stop();
                Log.i("return2","return2");
                stopSelf();
                 // return;



            }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // Let's get out of here
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }

            if (numread < 0) {

                bout.flush();
                stopSelf();


                Log.i("Bad read from stream", "Bad read from stream3");
                if(stream == null){
                    urlConn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();
                    urlConn.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 30);
                    urlConn.connect();
                    stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream(),bufsizeForDownload);


                }else{
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {  
                           public void run() {
                               Log.i("Bad read from stream", "Bad read from xyz");

                              context.stopService(startingIntent);
                               Log.i("return3","return3");
                              return;
                           }  
                        });  



                }

            } else if (numread >= 1) {

                bout.write(buf, 0, numread);

                totalBytesRead += numread;
                totalKbRead += totalBytesRead / 1000;
            }

            if (totalKbRead >= INTIAL_KB_BUFFER && stopping != true) {

                bout.flush();

                bout.close();
                bout = null;
                if (started == false) {
                    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            setupplayer();
                        }
                    };
                    Thread t = new Thread(r);
                    t.start();
                }

                totalBytesRead = 0;
                totalKbRead = 0;
            }

            if (stopping == true) {
                stream = null;

            }

        } while (stream != null);


    }


    /** oncompletelister for media player **/

    class listener implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            waitingForPlayer = false;

            long timeInMilli = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
            long timeToQuit = (1000 * 30) + timeInMilli; // add 30 seconds

            if (mp1playing) 
            {
                mp1.reset();
                removefile();
                mp1prepared = false;
                // Log.d(TAG, "mp1 is Free.");
                if (downloadingformp2) {
                    if (mp2preparing && stopping == false) {

                        waitingForPlayer = true;
                    }
                    while (mp2preparing && stopping == false) {
                        if (timeInMilli > timeToQuit) {

                            stopSelf();
                        }
                        timeInMilli = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                mp2.reset();
                removefile();
                mp2prepared = false;

                if (downloadingformp1) {
                    if (mp1preparing && stopping == false) {

                        waitingForPlayer = true;
                    }
                    while (mp1preparing && stopping == false) {
                        if (timeInMilli > timeToQuit) {

                            stopSelf();
                        }
                        timeInMilli = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (waitingForPlayer == true) {
                // we must have been waiting
                waitingForPlayer = false;
            }

            if (stopping == false) {


                if (mp1playing) {

                    mp2.start();

                    mp1playing = false;
                    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            setupplayer();
                        }
                    };
                    Thread t = new Thread(r);
                    t.start();
                } else {

                    mp1.start();

                    mp1playing = true;
                    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            setupplayer();
                        }
                    };
                    Thread t = new Thread(r);
                    t.start();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /** OnPreparedListener for media player **/

    class preparelistener implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            if (prepareState) {
                prepareState = false;
                mp1preparing = false;
                mp1prepared = true;

                if (started == false) {
                    started = true;

                    mp1.start();
                    mp1playing = true;
                    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            setupplayer();
                        }
                    };
                    Thread t = new Thread(r);
                    t.start();
                }
            } else {
                prepareState = true;
                mp2preparing = false;
                mp2prepared = true;

            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Set Up player(s)
     */
    public void setupplayer() {
        final String TAG = "setupplayer";

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    if (!mp1preparing && !mp1prepared) {

                        while (true) {
                            downloadingformp1 = true;
                            if (started == false)
                                break;
                            if (counter > preparecounter)
                                break;
                        }
                        File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), DOWNFILE+ preparecounter);
                        FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream(f);

                        mp1.setDataSource(ins.getFD());
                        mp1.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);//playing for live streaming


                        mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new listener());


                        mp1.setOnPreparedListener(new preparelistener());


                        if (started == false || waitingForPlayer == true){

                        }



                        mp1.prepareAsync();// .prepare();
                        mp1preparing = true;
                        downloadingformp1 = false;
                        preparecounter++;


                    } else if (!mp2preparing && !mp2prepared) {

                        while (true) {
                            downloadingformp2 = true;
                            if (started == false)
                                break;
                            if (counter > preparecounter)
                                break;
                        }
                        File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), DOWNFILE+ preparecounter);
                        FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream(f);



                        mp2.setDataSource(ins.getFD());
                        mp2.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


                        mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new listener());


                        mp2.setOnPreparedListener(new preparelistener());


                        mp2.prepareAsync();
                        mp2preparing = true;
                        downloadingformp2 = false;
                        preparecounter++;

                        // }

                    } else
                        Log.d(TAG, "No Media player is available to setup.");
                        return;

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    Log.e(TAG,"Can't find file. Android must have deleted it on a clean up ");
                    stop();

                    return;

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    stop();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    stop();

                }
            }

        };
        preparringthread = new Thread(r);
        preparringthread.start();



        try {

            preparringthread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void removefile() {

        File temp = new File(context.getCacheDir(), DOWNFILE + playedcounter);

        temp.delete();
        playedcounter++;
    }


    public boolean stop() {
        final String TAG = "STOP";


        stopping = true;
        try {

            if (mp1.isPlaying()){
                if (!(stream == null)) {
                    Log.i("IN STOP", "MP1 is nill");
                    stopSelf();
                }
                mp1.stop();
            }

            if (mp2.isPlaying()){
                Log.i("IN STOP", "MP2 is nill");

                if (!(stream == null)){
                    stopSelf();
                }
                mp2.stop();
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error stopping players");
        }

        if (stream != null) {

            try {
                stream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error closing open connection");
            }
        }
        stream = null;

        processHasStarted = false;
        processHasPaused = true;
        if (preparringthread != null) {
            preparringthread.interrupt();
        }

        stopSelf();

        return true;
    }


    public boolean isPlaying() {

        return processHasStarted;
    }

    public boolean isPause() {

        return processHasPaused;
    }

    private void raiseThreadPriority() {

        Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste a bit more of the logcat?

Comment: @Matthieu I had updated My LogCat Error

Answer (score 1):

The messages

```
GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 51742 objects / 1928072 bytes in 80ms
```

Are not really an error, it's just a sign that you keep allocating memory and releasing it which forces the garbage collector to run often. This is not very good for performance, but not going to cause your streaming to stop.

The real error is the file not found exception.

Going through your code quickly, what I believe is happening is that you keep storing all the streaming data into a file (without deleting what has been played already), so that file grows indefinitely and the device is eventually going to run out of space. When it's getting close to that, Android starts cleaning up temporary files and eventually that includes your streaming file since it is located in the `cache` directory.

My suggestion would be to use [`PipedInputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) and [`PipedOutputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) instead. You'll have to make sure to make sure to make it big enough for buffering the stream (but not too big since this will be in memory). But then you don't have to worry about the file growing.

If that does not work well (because for some reason you cannot buffer enough data in memory to play smoothly without running into problems with the network speed fluctuations), then you might have to create your own InputStream and OutputStream classes. Maybe using two files would be the easiest way (buffer in two files, go back and forth between those two, when the read pointer moves to the same file as the write pointer, you know you can discard the other one).

Comment: Thanks for your quick Reply, I'm new to Programming and andriod as well,Could you give me the Source code please,what i need to change from my Source code to work well the streaming?

Comment: Actually the Android MediaPlayer cannot take an InputStream (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257364/modifying-fileinputstream-for-mediaplayer-setdatasource). The best code I could find that should fit your needs is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343730/mediaplayer-stutters-at-start-of-mp3-playback/5432091#5432091

Comment: You can delete files with File.delete()... but that will delete the whole file. I don't think there is a good way to just delete what has been played at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is it actual now or not, but MediaPlayer can play live streams (at least audio/mpeg and audio/aacp). You don't need to predownload the content. Just call

```
MediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://123.176.41.8:8256");
```